# delay 10 secons is increasing arduino

Tags: delay, arduino

Why the delay of 10 seconds is not constant value, it is increasing ?

I am using arduino nano version 3. I set 9600 bps

```
void loop() {
      serialPrint("Saaabbb--hghgE");
}
void serialPrint(String message){
  Serial.println(millis());
  Serial.println(message);
  delay(10000);
}
```

OUTPUT

```
0
Saaabbb--hghgE
10000
Saaabbb--hghgE
20000
Saaabbb--hghgE
30001
Saaabbb--hghgE
40001
Saaabbb--hghgE
50001
Saaabbb--hghgE
60002
Saaabbb--hghgE
70003
Saaabbb--hghgE
80004
Saaabbb--hghgE
90004
Saaabbb--hghgE
100004
Saaabbb--hghgE
110005
Saaabbb--hghgE
120006
Saaabbb--hghgE
130007
Saaabbb--hghgE
140007
Saaabbb--hghgE
150007
```

Answer (score 1):

The extra 1 added every couple of commands is the delay caused by actually processing your code.
`Serial.println(millis())` takes time to complete so the total time is process time + your added delay.

For example:

```
void loop() {
      serialPrint("Saaabbb--hghgE");
}
void serialPrint(String message){
  Serial.println(millis()); //takes 0.5millis (for example)
  Serial.println(message);  //takes 0.5millis (for example)
  delay(10000); //takes 10000millis
}
```

Therefore total time from `millis()` is 10001.

Comment: thanks a lot, where did you found the time information for each line of code ?

Comment: That amount of time is not accurate, it was just for an example, to figure out how long exactly the code will take you need to disassemble it see how many commands there are, then based on your processor speed see how fast it would get done, but again that would still just be an estimation there are other factors that could effect how long the commands take

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's just the time needed to process your command. I don't know your project, but since my ones never needed the accuracy of a millisecond, I think you can just ignore it.